# Convert array of objects to lists

Tags: javascript

I am looking for the best way to conevert array of objects to one object with key and the value is list of all values for that key.

```
[ 
  { key : '11', value : '1100' },
  { key : '22', value : '2200' }
];
```

I want to go to something like:

```
[
  {
  key   : ['11','22'],
  value : ['1100','2200'],
  }
]
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: Do you have any code in that you tried? or any logic/psudocode that you can think of?

Comment: Loop through the array and then loop through keys of the object. Add them to an output object: `const output = {}; for(const o of array) for(const k in o) (output[k] ||= []).push(o[k])` Will work for any number of keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var array=  [
           { key : '11', value : '1100'},
           { key : '22', value : '2200' }
        ];
    
    var result=[{
      key: array.map(item=>item.key),
      value: array.map(item=>item.value)
    }];

    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = [{
    key: '11',
    value: '1100'
  },
  {
    key: '22',
    value: '2200'
  }
];

const keys = [];
const values = [];

input.forEach(({ key, value }) => {
  keys.push(key);
  values.push(value);
})

const result =  [{
  key: keys,
  value: values
}]

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might solve your problem !

```
 let array = [{
  key: '11',
  value: '1100'
},
  {
    key: '22',
    value: '2200'
  }];

let keys = [], values = [];

array.forEach(key_val => {
  keys.push(key_val.key);
  values.push(key_val.value)
})

array = {
  key: keys,
  value: values
}
   // It will return object 
console.log(array)
   // As requested now it returns array
array =  Object.entries(array);
console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

that ?

```js
const data = [ 
  { key : '11', value : '1100' },
  { key : '22', value : '2200' }
]
 
const result = data.reduce((r,{key,value}) =>
  {
  r[0].key.push(key)
  r[0].value.push(value)
  return r
  },[{key:[],value:[]}])


console.log(result)
```